# When Yosef interprets Pharoah's dream, is he also trying to fulfill his own dream?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yosef, parashat-vayeishev, miketz

Yosef's 2nd dream was that his brothers father and mother would eventually bow to him.

Yosef interprets Pharaoh's dream to mean that there would be 7 years of famine. What I find interesting is that after he interprets the dream he advises Pharaoh to appoint someone in charge of storing food for the eventual famine. Granted, he doesn't specifically say that HE should be the one in charge.

I'm curious if any commentary may have stated that by giving this advice Yosef was thinking that this was the method to have his initial dream fulfilled. Maybe, he thought that Pharaoh would appoint him the one in charge of distributing the food, and eventually, because of the famine stretching in to Cana'an, his family would have to come and bow to him.

Comment: You don’t think he learned his lesson from the end of Vayeishev that for him hishtadlus was inappropriate?

Comment: @DonielF It's an interesting take. However, I think there's a "thin border" between "hishtadlut" and making the best of an opportunity. It's not as if he asked to be called to Pharaoh to interpret his dream.

Comment: Nor did he ask for the winemaker to go to Paroh. But since he was going anyway, he took the opportunity. I agree it’s a slightly different situation, but I’d think it’s similar enough.

Comment: I had always understood it as Yosef trying to get the job, but not necessarily because of the dreams

Answer (score 4):

After a quick look through the Mefarshim (Bereishis 41:33), I don't believe any of them would hold like what you suggest.  [Almost all commentaries](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/41.33#e0n7) understand Yosef's suggestion to Pharaoh as part of the dream interpretation, and not a suggestion with himself in mind.

However, [Ramban](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/41.33#e0n7) disagrees and says that Yosef said this opportunistically, and was intending to be the one chosen for this job, although he does not comment on if it was his intention to fulfill his dream through this:

> ואמר יוסף כל זה בעבור שיבחרו אותו כי החכם עיניו בראשו.

However, I believe that it was just so he could get out of jail and become rich, not to fulfill his dreams.  This is proven by Ramban's understanding of the second Passuk that relates to this question, which is Bereishis 42:9 ([Mefarshim at this link](http://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Bereshit/42.9#e0n7)):

> וַיִּזְכֹּ֣ר יוֹסֵ֔ף אֵ֚ת הַחֲלֹמ֔וֹת אֲשֶׁ֥ר חָלַ֖ם לָהֶ֑ם וַיֹּ֤אמֶר אֲלֵהֶם֙ מְרַגְּלִ֣ים אַתֶּ֔ם לִרְא֛וֹת אֶת־עֶרְוַ֥ת הָאָ֖רֶץ בָּאתֶֽם׃

While many Mefarshim (Rashi and others, see Ramban's quote below) understand this Passuk to mean that he realized that they were now fulfilled (and as a result, this does not **necessarily** imply that he had forgotten the dreams before this), Ramban, again disagrees, and understands it simply that **he had forgotten the dreams until now**, and because he saw almost all of his brothers there, he remembered them, and began planning how to fulfill them **only at this point**. Here is the text of the Ramban:

> ויזכר יוסף את החלומות אשר חלם להם – עליהם, וידע שנתקיימו, שהרי השתחוו לו. לשון רש״י.
>   (והנכון בעיני) [ולפי דעתי שהדבר בהפך] כי יאמר הכתוב כי בראות יוסף את אחיו משתחוים לו, זכר כל החלומות אשר חלם להם. (ואמר בלבו עתה יתקיימו כלם עליכן) [וידע שלא נתקיים אחד מהם בפעם הזאת, כי יודע בפתרונם כי כל אחיו ישתחוו לו בתחילה, מן החלום הראשון: והנה אנחנו מאלמים אלומים, כי ״אנחנו״ ירמוז לכל אחיו אחד עשר, ופעם שנית ישתחוו לו השמש והירח ואחד עשר כוכבים, מן החלום השני, וכיון שלא ראה בנימן עמהם] חשב זאת התחבולה שיעליל עליהם כדי שיביאו גם בנימין אחיו אליו, לקיים (גם החלום האחר שאמר: ואחד עשר כוכבים משתחוים לי, וזה טעם וירדו אחי יוסף עשרה, כי החלום הראשון היה אל העשרה, כי בהם אמר: ויגד אותו לאחיו ויוסיפו עוד שנוא אותו, ולהם אמר: והנה אנחנו מאלמים אלומים, והנה בנימין איננו בכלל הזה, ועתה נתקיים החלום הראשון בהשתחוייתם אליו. והחלום השני לא יוכל להתקיים עד בא בנימין גם אביו.) [החלום הראשון תחילה ועל כן לא רצה להגיד להם אני יוסף אחיכם, ולאמר מהרו ועלו אל אבי וישלח העגלות, כאשר עשה עמהם בפעם השניה, כי היה אביו בא מיד בלא ספק. ואחרי שנתקיים החלום הראשון. הגיד להם לקיים החלום השני. ולולי כן, היה יוסף חוטא חטא גדול לצער את אביו ולהעמידו ימים רבים בשכול ואבל על שמעון ועליו, ואף אם היה רצונו לצער את אחיו קצת, איך לא יחמול על שיבת אביו. אבל את הכל עשה יפה בעתו לקיים החלומות כי ידע שיתקיימו באמת.

In short, I don't think there are any Mefarshim who hold like the Ramban in 41:33, and argue on the simple understanding of "and he remembered" in 42:9.

Feedback welcome!